# Error PHP al unserializar objeto guardado en variable de sesión

Tags: php

Estoy iniciando en este lenguaje y no se exactamente que hice

Este es el error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: unserialize(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type string, __PHP_Incomplete_Class given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicio\web\empleado\buscar.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicio\web\empleado\buscar.php(6): unserialize(Object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicio\web\empleado\buscar.php on line 6

Esta es la parte del codigo que da el error.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../modelo/Empleado.php';
$msj = @$_REQUEST["msj"];
$e = @$_SESSION["empleado.find"];
$e = unserialize($e);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guardar objetos en variables de sesión es problemático.
Cuando los recuperas, como estás haciendo con `$_SESSION["empleado.find"]`, no se hace correctamente, estás obteniendo un objeto incompleto y por eso te da error al unserializar.

Es necesario que definas la clase antes de iniciar la sesión, osea, pon el require de la clase antes de `session_start()`:

```
require_once '../../modelo/Empleado.php';
session_start();
```

Pruébalo a ver.